# The links in the Bluemix confirmation email do not work

Tags: ibm-cloud

I signed up for the Bluemix trial, received the confirmation email, but both links in the email end up at this URL: https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/idaas/public/tamlogin.jsp which never responds. Eventually the browser timesout with this message: The server at www-947.ibm.com is taking too long to respond.
This has been consistent for the past 2 weeks. Anyone seen this and know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try to access Bluemix without VPN connection? I believe your issue is related to VPN client. If connecting to Bluemix without VPN works, please upgrade your VPN client to latest version and try to connect to Bluemix with VPN connection.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. An upgraded VPN client resolved the issue. For someone who might be reading this, experiencing the same problem, I was on ATT VPN client version 8.2.0.3003 and moved up to 9.3.2.3001.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem has been resolved. Enjoy!